# How do I pass a value from dynamic generated combobox to the next form's combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a windows form project and facing difficulty in passing the dynamically generated control value to the other form's normal control value.

My code is:

```
        int c = 0;
        int p = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = VerticalScroll.Minimum;
           // panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = HorizontalScroll.Minimum;

            ComboBox txtRun3 = new ComboBox();
            txtRun3.Name = "txtDynamic" + c++ ;
            txtRun3.Location = new Point(30, 18 + (30 * c))
            panel1.Controls.Add(txtRun3);
           txtRun3.Focus();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 f4 = new Form4();
        Button bt = sender as Button; 
       ComboBox cb2 = bt.Tag as ComboBox;
        f4.Combo.Text = bt.Text;
         }
```

I am getting the error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a public property in the `Form4`

```
public ComboBox Combo
{
    get
    {
        return this.comboBox1;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.comboBox1 = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can access  it in this way:

```
Form4 f4 = new Form4();
Button bs = (Button) sender;
f4.Combo.Text = bs.Text;
```

Comment: The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item this error is coming in the combo

Comment: @shariq_khan: I assume that the sender is the button, edited my answer.

Comment: sir can you help me, i am in big problem here,

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Set a breakpoint where you get the exception and inspect the values. What is `null`, `Combo`? What do you need this for: `ComboBox cb2 = bt.Tag as ComboBox` when you're not using that variable at all there?

Comment: i have written this in the second button click event
 
Form4 f4 = new Form4();
Button bs = (Button)sender;
f4.Combo.Text = bs.Text;
f4.Show();
and after the form opens it open with the button name not the combobox's text.

Comment: i have edited what you told but the problem is the form4 combobox opens with the button name and  not with the text of the dynamically generated combobox

Comment: Sorry, but why do you think that the button's `Tag` property would contains the `ComboBox`? I must admit that i don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: sir i want to transfer the combobox's text to the form4's combobox when the button is clicked.

Comment: @shariq_khan: You have added the combobox to your panel. Is it the only combobox there? Then you can use `panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().First()` to get the reference.

Comment: yess i got,
thank you sir. and if i want to transfer all the combobox's text, i.e all the combobox from the panel, their text to one combobox? the can be possible?

Comment: `panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()` retuns all comboboxes. If you want a `List<string>` of all cb's text: `List<string> allText = panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Select(cb => cb.Text).ToList() `

Comment: then can allText be usefull for transfering all the combobox's text to the one combobox of form4?

Comment: Yes, you  could use it as `DataSource` for the other combobox (if you want).

Comment: datasource?? how can i use that? can you simplify. please sir

Comment: Yes, [**`DataSource`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x8160f6f.aspx) : `comboBox1.DataSource = allText;`

Comment: wow,it was awsome sir, and if i have generated 4 textbox and i want to transfer the text of that to the next form's textbox like
textbox1.text,textbox2.text,textbox3,text,textbox4.text
canbe datastore usefull in this case?

Comment: No, a TextBox has no `DataSource` porperty. You can get all textboxes via `panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`. Then you could loop the f.e. with a `foreach` to tranfer their text to the same textbox on the other form(same Name).

Comment: textbox is dynamically generated so foreach loop is possible in this case, sir?

Comment: @shariq_khan: Yes, the same as with the combobox, i've showed you the code to get the dynamic textboxes in my last comment. `foreach(TextBox txt in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()){// set the other textboxes text here}`

Comment: foreach(TextBox txt in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
// set the other textboxes text here
sir the textbox is dynamically generated so what to do, i dont have name of all the textbox which is formed, if i have name then i can transfer it to the next form
}

Comment: @shariq_khan: Where are the dynamic textboxes on `Form4`, also in a panel like `panel1`? Then you can use above code(...`OfType<TextBox>()...` to find all textboxes on your first form and the similar code to find all textboxes on the other form. Then you just have to loop the first textboxes and try to find the same textbox in the other list and update their text. Ask another question since it's difficult to tell in comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
can you help me sir