# How to transfer the text from dynamically generated user control to a textbox

Tags: c#

I have a windows form in which I have a `button1` and when that is clicked a `UserControl` that is added dynamically to the code is this:

```
    int c = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int v;
        v = c++;
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = VerticalScroll.Minimum;
        UserControl1 us = new UserControl1();
        us.Name = "us" + v;
        us.Location = new Point(50, 5 + (30 * v));
        us.Tag = btn;
        panel1.Controls.Add(us);
     }
```

That `UserControl` contains 4 controls 2 comboboxes and 2 textboxes

i.e `combobox1`, `combobox2`, `textbox1` and `textbox2`

There are 4 textboxes which are on the same form

`still-textbox1`, `still-textbox2`, `still-textbox3` and `still-textbox4`

There is `button2` and it will transfer the text to comboboxes and textboxes which are `oldcombobox1`, `oldcombobox2`, `oldtextbox1` and `oldtextbox2`

When `button1` is clicked twice it will add two `UserControls` to the form.
I want to transfer the text in the following format

`oldcombobox1.text = still-textbox1.text + "," + combobox1.text(which is dynamically generated) + "," + combobox1.text (which is dynamically generated)` etc all the `combobox1` text from the UserControl (which is added dynamically)

`oldcombobox2.text = still-textbox2.text + "," + combobox2.text (which is dynamically generated) + "," + combobox2.text (which is dynamically generated)` etc all the `combobox2` text from the UserControl (which is added dynamically)

`oldtextbox1.text = still-textbox3 + "," + textboox1.text (which is dynamically generated) + "," + textbox1.text (which is dynamically generated)` etc all the `textbox1` text from the `UserControl` (which is added dynamically)

Means when the `still-textbox1.text = first`
and when dynamic `UserControl` is added three times it will contain 3 times `combobox1` then the `oldcombobox1` should contain:

`first`, `combobox1.text`, `combobox1.text`, `combobox1.text`

I have made this code but it doesn't work

```
  foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
   {
     if (ctrl is UserControl)
     {
         UserControl1 myCrl = ctrl as UserControl1;
         oldcombobox1.text = still-textbox1.text + "," + myCrl.comboBox1.Text;
         oldcombobox2.Text =still-textbox2.text + "," + myCrl.comboBox2.Text;
         oldtextbox1.Text = still-textbox3.text + "," + myCrl.textBox1.Text;
         oldtextbox2.Text.Text = still-textbox4.text + "," + myCrl.textBox2.Text;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Create public String properties in your UserControl1 class, that give you access to the desired strings within the control.

Comment: mithrandir? what ? i didint understood can you write and understand the code? then i will get what do you want to say

Comment: @shariq_khan I think Mithrandir's answer answers you.

Comment: @nawful no sir i want in this format

still-textbox.text ,  combobox1.text , combobox2.text etc etc all the dynamically generated combobox it is not happening that answer is not doing it is same what i was doing

Comment: @shariq_khan few things. 1) Tell me what output you get now. 2) what is `still -` ? How is that possible to write it? 3) Can you post two screenshots of your application, one of your application (which includes all the user controls, buttons etc) and two, of the desired output after the button click? 4) what are your "dynamically added comboboxes"? I see only a single usercontrol being added dynamically from your code.

Comment: @shariq_khan: One suggestion you should work on naming convention

Comment: @ nawful can you help me here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170268/how-to-update-the-datagridview-when-editing-is-made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your class `UserControl1` (great name btw ;-) ) something like this for every string you want to access from another object, in this case the string of `textBox1`:

```
public String FirstTextBoxText 
{
   get { return this.textBox1.Text; }
}
```

Then you can say in your Form class:

```
 if (ctrl is UserControl)
 {
     UserControl1 myCrl = ctrl as UserControl1;
     // ...
     oldtextbox1.Text = still-textbox3.text + "," + myCrl.FirstTextBoxText;
 }
```

It's still horrible code, but it will work.

Comment: sir, but what when button is clicked four times?
this code will resturn this kind pattern?
still-textbox3.text,textbox3.text,textbox3.text,textbox3.text,textbox3.text???
old,first,second,third,fourth?

Comment: @shariq_khan: it's quite hard to grasp what you want to do actually, at least for me. I tried to answer your question, how to "transfer the text from dynamically generated user control to a textbox". What you need to do to process the texts in a way that meets your requirements, i honestly can't say.

Comment: i want all the firts comboboxes which are dynamycally generated with comma and at the start it should be still-textbox3.text
can you do? please sir i  am in truble and i have tried a lot but cant get rid of such problem my whole project is done(its simple) but this is creating problem
sorry sir... but can you do this string builder???

Comment: @shariq_khan: this forum is for answering technical questions, not fixing your projects. That would be hard to do, even if had the time and inclination, an the information you've given.

Comment: sir this is technical question only... all one here ask question which they will implement in some or the other project.. i am also asking help here...

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with events.

Create a class that inherits from EventArgs:
(I prefer VB, you can traslate)

```
Public Class ControlEventArgs
  Inherits EventArgs

  Public Property Value1 As String = String.Empty
  Public Property Value2 As String = String.Empty
  Public Property Value3 As String = String.Empty
  Public Property Value4 As String = String.Empty

End Class
```

Then in your Control add the event:

```
Public Event ValueSubmittal As EventHandler(Of ControlEventArgs)
```

In your Button2_Click handler:

```
RaiseEvent ValueSubmittal(me, new ControlEventArgs With {.Value1=comboBox1.Text, .Value2 = comboBox2.Text, .Value3 = textBox1.Text, .Value4 = textBox2.Text}
```

And in your form where you dynamically create the controls you need to hook up the event handler:

```
AddHandler myNewControl.ValueSubmittal, AddressOf ValueSubmittalHandler
```

And the ValueSubmittalHandler:

```
Private Sub ValueSubmittalHandler(sender as Object, e As ControlEventArgs)
  formControl1.Text = e.Value1
  formControl2.Text = e.Value2
  '  etc...
End Sub
```

Comment: As stated in the answer.. you can translate.

Comment: i am new to c# and i dont know anything about vb.. just heard of that
sorry

Comment: I do not have the time or inclination to translate this for you.  There are plenty of online translation services.  Or you can ask around in the forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class level variable:

```
    private UserControl1 us1;
    private UserControl1 us2;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int v;
        v = c++;
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = VerticalScroll.Minimum;

        if(us == null) 
        {
            //this is the first time the control is created
            us1 = new UserControl1();
            us1.Name = "us" + v;
            us1.Location = new Point(50, 5 + (30 * v));
            us1.Tag = btn;        
            panel1.Controls.Add(us1);
        }
        else if(us2 ==null)
        {
            us2 = new UserControl1();
            //whatever code you want to execute to change second one
            //you can access first control as us1.xxx
            panel1.Controls.Add(us2);

        }
        else
        {
           //3rd 4th etc...
        }


     }
```

Comment: what you have written have you understood the question sir

Comment: @shariq_khan sorry I misunderstood the question and changed the answer to add a second control